# How to know what to limit the variables to when computing probability marginal distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following question:

> Consider the random variables X and Y with joint density function
>
> $f(x,y)= x+y, 0≤x,y≤1$
> $f(x,y)=0,$ elsewhere.
>
> (a) Find the marginal distributions of X and Y .

When computing the marginal distribution for $y$, the variable $x$ had the integral limits as $0$ and $1$ however $x+y$ is valid for $x$ between $0$ and infinity, how to know that I should limit $x$ to one?

Comment: $f_X(x)=\int_0^{1} (x+y)dy=x+\frac  1 2$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes but why is the integral limits 0 and 1? that is my question

Comment: It is given that $f(x,y)=0$ of $y>1$ or $y <0$

Comment: I think you are mis-reading the inequalities $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$. This is not $0 \leq x$ and $y \leq 1$. It is supposed to mean that both $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: oh thank you, solved then!

Comment: @Sergio Feel free to write an answer to this question and accept it. That is the generally accepted practice, to reduce the number of unanswered questions on the website.

Comment: @Math1000 thank you, didn't know about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I did was due to misreading the inequalities, it is written that "$0≤x,y≤1$ which is equal to $0≤x≤1$ and $0≤y≤1$ and NOT $0≤x$ and $y≤1$ like I thought.

Note: All credits goes to user Kavi Rama Murthy in comments.